# ¿Cómo puedo habilitar Docker y Virtualbox en la misma PC?

Tags: docker, windows10, virtualbox

Quisiera practicar con docker, pero tras instalarlo me sale un mensaje que indica que VirtualBox dejará de funcionar si le doy aceptar, y no deseo dejar de utilizar mi VB. Tengo Windows 10 Pro.

¿Cómo puedo correr las dos cosas en mi misma máquina?

### Intentos

De momento hice lo que dice [este post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx)

en el powershell puse:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper-V"
```

pero me marca

> The copy command specified is not valid.
>
> Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
>
> The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Quizás lo más sencillo sea que uses VirtualBox para ejecutar una máquina virtual en la que tengas un Linux (por ejemplo, Ubuntu Server) y en esa máquina virtual instales docker para experimentar con él. A fin de cuentas la gran mayoría de imágenes docker sólo funcionarán bajo linux (y sospecho que probablemente instalar docker en windows lo que haga en realidad sea crear un linux virtual sobre el que docker correría)

Comment: @abulafia con la última versión de VB es posible, gracias :)

Comment: Pasa que la versión oficial de docker utiliza Hyper-V en windows, lo cual no es compatible con VB, por lo que si tienes uno, no tienes el otro, es una limitación de Windows, pero puedes hacer como yo que no tengo windows pro, entonces me toca usar si o si VirtualBox y entonces utilizo [esta](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) versión que si se ejecuta bajo virtualbox, solo que obviamente es mas lento